# How does msys2 display console output from non-console application?

Tags: c, windows, console, mingw, msys2

If I compile this source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
  printf("Done!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

with `gcc hello.c -o hello  -mwindows` under [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) using `mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` toolchain, and then run it from inside msys2 I'll see:

[image]

At the same time if I call this same executable from powershell (or cmd) I'll see:

[image]

To be honest, given the `-mwindows` which is saying to produce a windows executable as opposed to console one, I'm not surprised at the latter - I've seen it many times.

But how does msys2 manage to display that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few differences between a console and GUI application on Windows and the C run-time stdio code usually does not care, it only cares about the standard Win32 handles.

The main difference is how `CreateProcess` in the parent application works.

- A console application gets hooked up to the parents standard Win32 handles if the parent has a console. If the parent does not have a console, a new console window is created for the application. The parent can pass optional flags to `CreateProcess` to force/deny a new console.
- A GUI application is not hooked up to the standard Win32 handles and no new console is created.

Powershell.exe is a real console application and it can use the default `CreateProcess` handling. Because your application is not a console application it will be created without standard handles and therefore it has nowhere to write to.

The msys2 terminal application is probably not a real console application and probably calls `CreateProcess` with forced handles (`STARTF_USESTDHANDLES`). These handles are probably handles to pipes. Your application will see these handles as redirected stdio handles and execute in a similar fashion as how cmd.exe would perform `yourconsoleapp.exe | otherconsoleapp.exe`.

Comment: Yes, MSYS2 uses named pipes for standard I/O. It's a common problem for console applications that use full buffering when writing to a pipe or disk file, with workarounds such as winpty.

Comment: As to CMD, interestingly it temporarily modifies its own standard handles and relies on inheritance rather than using the `STARTUPINFO` standard handles. It first tries to call `CreateProcessW` with `bInheritHandles` as `TRUE`. If this succeeds, the child is created with a copy of the parents standard handle values, whether they're inherited or not. The internal `ConsoleHandle` is not inherited to a non-console app, but inheritable standard I/O handles are inherited in all cases, so we can do something like `.\hello.exe | more`, given "hello.exe" is the OP's non-console build.

Comment: If we instead run a file by filetype association, CMD uses `ShellExecuteExW`, in which case the result depends on whether the associated executable is a console app. `ShellExecuteExW` does not inherit handles, so `file.ext | more` won't work if ".EXT" is associated with our non-console "hello.exe". If we build "hello.exe" as a console app, it will work because `NtCreateUserProcess` implicitly duplicates (not inherits) standard handles to a console app.